# How to edit fullcalendar event content

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am succeed in embedding the fullcalendar control in my asp.net mvc application. it is running perfect. But I want to edit existing event, what I have to do?

**Edited:**
ok I have done with successfully Edit event in fullcalender control. but after edit the event, it assumes it as new event and rather replace another event it shows me one more event. and if i refreshes page, then it shows properly. So I think after I edit the event, some how i want to render / call again / refresh page.

Here is the code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var date = new Date();
      var d = date.getDate();
      var m = date.getMonth();
      var y = date.getFullYear();
      var officerid = document.getElementById('officerid').value;
      url = "/TasksToOfficer/Calender/" + officerid;


      var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
              border: 0
          },
         eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

              var title = prompt('Event Title:', calEvent.title, { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false} });

              if (title) {
                  var st = calEvent.start;
                  var ed = calEvent.end;
                  var aldy = calEvent.allDay;
                  var dt = calEvent.date;
                  var iden = calEvent.id;

                  calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                           {
                                               title: title,
                                               start: st,
                                               end: ed,
                                               allDay: aldy
                                           },
                                           true);


                  var date = new Date(st);
                  var NextMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
                  var dateString = (date.getDate()) + '/' + NextMonth + '/' + date.getFullYear();



                  if (officerid) {
                      $.ajax(
                                                    {

                                                        type: "POST",
                                                        url: "/TasksToOfficer/Create",
                                                        data: "officerid=" + officerid + "&description=" + title + "&date=" + dateString + "&IsForUpdate=true&EventId=" + iden,
                                                        success: function(result) {

                                                            if (result.success) $("#feedback input").attr("value", ""); // clear all the input fields on success

                                                        },
                                                        error: function(req, status, error) {

                                                        }
                                                    });


                  }
              }

          }

              ,

          selectable: true,
          selectHelper: true,
          select: function(start, end, allDay) {
              var title = prompt('Event Title:', { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }

              });
              if (title) {
                  calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                                                 {
                                                                     title: title,
                                                                     start: start,
                                                                     end: end,
                                                                     allDay: allDay
                                                                 },
                                              false); // This is false , because do not show same event on same date after render from server side.
                  var date = new Date(start);

                  var NextMonth = date.getMonth() + 1; // Reason: it is bacause of month array it starts from 0

                  var dateString = (date.getDate()) + '/' + NextMonth + '/' + date.getFullYear();

                  if (officerid) {
                      $.ajax(
                                                                    {

                                                                        type: "POST",
                                                                        url: "/TasksToOfficer/Create",
                                                                        data: "officerid=" + officerid + "&description=" + title + "&date=" + dateString + "&IsForUpdate=false",
                                                                        success: function(result) {

                                                                            if (result.success) $("#feedback input").attr("value", ""); // clear all the input fields on success
                                                                            //$("#feedback_status").slideDown(250).text(result.message); // show status message with animation
                                                                        },
                                                                        error: function(req, status, error) {

                                                                        }
                                                                    });
                  }
              }
              calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
          },
          editable: true,
          lazyFetching: true,
          events: url //this will call the action from controller and show the saved events in db, the result of the action should be in proper formate.
      });
  });
```

I tried here with refetchEvent, renderEvents for call back , but not worked. Is here any other issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of calling `renderEvent` you will have to call [updateEvent](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/updateEvent/) when you change one.  Also notice that you have to provide the "real" calendar event to updateEvent, not one that you make up.  So your code should go like this:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          var title = prompt('Event Title:', calEvent.title, { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false} });

          if (title){
              calEvent.title = title;
              calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent',calEvent);
          }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but this is not working for me. I am not only updating on page, but also updating it in database.I tried this before , but not works for me.

Comment: @Lalit: works for me, see here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/8hNGJ/  The only meaningful difference between my example and your code is that I'm using `$('#calendar')` instead of `calendar` when calling `updateEvent`

Comment: @Ryley , I agree after take a looking your code. it is working for me too, but it is not rendering updated content. else if i click again on same event, in prompt i am getting updated value. but after this line : calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent',calEvent);
 It is not execute any thing. I tried to put alert('hi'); after this line , but it is not executed... an all melody of this functionality is comming after this line..so, what should be the problem withi this line ?

Comment: Fine this is working now , silly mistake was there in spell. perfectly working now ...Thanks

Comment: @Lalit, if my answer wasn't the right one, maybe you can add an answer that explains what did work?  Even if its just a spelling mistake, it might help someone else later!

Comment: sure, I had used my variable name as "calender", where as I had mistaken in this "calendar"...so this was the mistake... this is silly I agree, but have to be in attention about mistake like this... @ Ryley,Your code is working fine. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It is Working for me and can update the event in db ..

```
eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:', event.title);
          if (title){
                event.title = title;
                var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                 $.ajax({
                        url: base_url+"calendar/edit_events",
                        data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (response) {
                            //alert("hi");
                            displayMessage("Updated Successfully");
                            window.location.href = base_url+"calendar/events"

                        }
                    });
                 calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                        },
                true
                        );

          }
           calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
```

Comment: Could you pin point what is the difference with OP's code? I saw it, but it is your job to be precise so others can understand easily.